# Display image with Python-Flask template engine

Tags: python, base64

I want to send binary image data to a template via Flask (to avoid buffering from browser). Python file is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import base64
from flask import Flask,make_response,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def showdata():

    fp = open("sp.png","rb")
    sp = base64.b64encode(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    fp = open("sg.png","rb")
    sg = base64.b64encode(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    wav = None

    resp = make_response(render_template('index.html',sg=sg,sp=sp))
    
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000,debug=True)
```

HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Show Timeswipe Measurements!</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- show data and spectrum -->
    <img id='spectrum' src='data:image/png;base64,{{ sp }}'>
  
    <!-- show spectrogram -->
    <img id='spectrogram' src='data:image/png;base64,{{ sg }}'>

    <!-- show wav -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Images are not shown. The src is `<img id='spectrum' src='data:image/png;base64,b&#39;iVBOR...`, i.e. there seems to be some additional characters at the beginning of the image `b&#39;i`.

What would be the right way to send binary image data via template engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution.

Changing the code as follows

```
sp = base64.b64encode(fp.read()).decode()
sg = base64.b64encode(fp.read()).decode()
```

does the job.